# Scala Spark creating a new column in the dataframe based on the aggregate count of values in another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe like the on below

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|   ID|      date|  count   |
+-----+----------+----------+
|54500|2016-05-02|         0|
|54500|2016-05-09|         0|
|54500|2016-05-16|         0|
|54500|2016-05-23|         0|
|54500|2016-06-06|         0|
|54500|2016-06-13|         0|
|54441|2016-06-20|         0|
|54441|2016-06-27|         0|
|54441|2016-07-04|         0|
|54441|2016-07-11|         0|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

I want to add an additional column that contains the count of records for a specific id in the dataframe while avoiding the for loop . The target dataframe looks like below

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|   ID|      date|  count   |
+-----+----------+----------+
|54500|2016-05-02|         6|
|54500|2016-05-09|         6|
|54500|2016-05-16|         6|
|54500|2016-05-23|         6|
|54500|2016-06-06|         6|
|54500|2016-06-13|         6|
|54441|2016-06-20|         4|
|54441|2016-06-27|         4|
|54441|2016-07-04|         4|
|54441|2016-07-11|         4|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Tried this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

var s = Window.partitionBy("ID")
var df2 = df.withColumn("count", count.over(s))
```

this is giving error

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method count in object functions of type (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[Any,Long]
and  method count in object functions of type (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
match expected type ?
```

Comment: Spark Window is that you need

Comment: did that i am getting error

Comment: @Leothorn can you please provide error details

Comment: I have adde dthe error as well

Comment: try count(df("count"))

Comment: It worked can you explain the logic in your answer ?

Comment: It worked can you explain the logic in your answer ?

Comment: ideally your IDE should complain while writing code (Cannot Resolve overloaded method) ... when you do count.over you are not mentioning which method to call .... so in runtime it found two potential methods ***def count(e: Column): Column*** and ***def count(columnName: String): TypedColumn[Any, Long]*** so it errors out saying your method call is not clear and i'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below approach:

```
 import spark.implicits._

val df1 = List(54500, 54500, 54500, 54500, 54500, 54500, 54441, 54441, 54441, 54441).toDF("ID")
val df2 = df1.groupBy("ID").count()
df1.join(df2, Seq("ID"), "left").show(false)

+-----+-----+
|ID   |count|
+-----+-----+
|54500|6    |
|54500|6    |
|54500|6    |
|54500|6    |
|54500|6    |
|54500|6    |
|54441|4    |
|54441|4    |
|54441|4    |
|54441|4    |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Answer is wrong because you are reducing the number of rows in final dataframe .

Comment: Oh! sorry, i didn't check that. edited the post, please have a look.